# Taylor polynomial and degree

Tags: terminology, taylor-expansion

I read that one can form Taylor polynomials for some functions, like $$\sin x\approx x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!}.$$
Is it correct to say that $\sin x$ has no Taylor polynomial with center 0 of order six or is the sixth order Taylor polynomial actually $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!}$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function might help

Comment: It is the second.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/201523/1242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, it is actually the same as that of order $5$. Note that if $T_{n,a}$ is the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ about $a$ of $f$, then $\deg(T)\leq n$, as it happens in this case.